# jQuery clear checkboxes when hiding div?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a jQuery script that will display specific divs depending on which select option has been selected.

Here's the code for that:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.viewMap = {
    '' : jQuery([]),
    '1' : jQuery('.company_1'),
    '2' : jQuery('.company_2')
  };
  jQuery('#companyid').change(function() {
    jQuery.each(jQuery.viewMap, function() { this.hide(); });
    jQuery.viewMap[jQuery(this).val()].show();
  });
});
```

(example div)

```
<div class="company_1" style="display: none;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="classifications[Miner]" id="classifications[Miner]" /> Spec/Rough
  <input type="checkbox" name="classifications[Dealer]" id="classifications[Dealer]" /> Dealer
</div>
```

I'd like it to clear all the checkboxes inside the div (.company_1, .company_2 etc) if someone selects a different option. If that makes sense? :)

Thank you!

Comment: So you want a radio button instead?

Comment: FYI, brackets aren't allowed for ids. http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/attrs.html

Comment: @strager - naw I need checkboxes, users can select multiple answers.. 

@seth - thanks for the info about the brackets in ids :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unchecking a checkbox is achieved by removing the attribute named "checked".  Try:

```
jQuery.each(jQuery.viewMap, function() {
    this.hide();
    jQuery('input:checkbox', this).removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

@David Andres
thanks for pointing me in the right direction I couldn't get your code to work, but used:

```
$("div.company_1 input:checked").removeAttr("checked");
```

which did work.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$("div.company_1 input[type:checkbox]").removeAttr("checked");
```